# ssh not working correctly with sudo

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, sudo

Good morning everyone!  I have a bash script starting automatically when the system boots via the .profile file in the users home directory:

sudo menu.sh

The script starts just as expected however, when calling things like ssh UN@ADDRESS inside the script, the known_hosts file gets placed in the /root/.ssh directory instead of the user account calling the script!  I have tried modifying .profile to call 'sudo -E menu.sh' and 'sudo -H menu.sh', but both fail to have the known_hosts file created in the users home directory that's calling the script.  My /etc/sudoers is as follows:

```
# Declarations
Defaults env_keep += "HOME USER"

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
user    ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks
Dave

UPDATE: so what I did as a work around is go through the script and add 'sudo -u $USER' before specific calls (since sudo is supposed to keep the $USER env var).  This to me seems like a very bad way of resolving this problem.  It sudo is supposed to keep the USER and HOME directory variables upon launching menu.sh, why would I need to explicitly call sudo once again as a specific user in order to retain that information (even though sudo is being told to keep it via the /etc/sudoers file).  No clue, but wanted to update this post for anyone that comes across it until a better solution can be found.

Comment: Sorry, but a .profile script in a users home directory is typically _not_ executed when the system is started. It is only executed (if at all), when that user does a login to the system.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment arkascha.  The script is loading as designed, so there isn't any issues with the .profile script.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: I didn't mean to say that the script is not getting executed. I just wanted to point out that the question is unprecise. About the issue: certainly a known_hosts file is generated inside roots home directory, since it is the root user that spawns another process (ssh client here). So why do you claim that sudo is not working correctly? It works exactly as expected.

Comment: The question isn't about .profile, its about ssh and sudo. I was including that to give the most info as possible as that call may need to be adjusted.

Comment: why would the file get generated in the root's home directory when sudo is being told to preserve the home directory of the caller?

Comment: As said: because you spawn a new process by calling the ssh client.

Comment: Doesn't the new process take on the environment of the parent?  At any rate, how do I fix the problem?

Comment: Sorry, not sure currently, I'd have to try around myself... My first approach would be to use the `exec` command which replaces the current process instead of spawning a new one. But as said: not sure.

Comment: Just added 'exec' before each 'ssh' call in the script, but the results are the same.  Also attempted to call the script with the '-E' and '-H' options to sudo without any luck.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: What about changing the `HOME` environment variable before spawning the ssh proces?

Comment: That didn't work either.  It is important to note that I have the following line added right above the 'ssh' call and it displays correct information:    echo "user is :${USER}: home is :${HOME}:"

Answer (score 1):

Regarding OpenSSH, the default location for known_hosts is `~/.ssh/known_hosts`. Ssh doesn't honor $HOME when expanding a "~" in a filename. It looks up the user's actual home directory and uses that. When you run ssh as root, it's going to interpret that pathname relative to root's home directory no matter what you've set HOME to.

You could try setting the ssh parameter `UserKnownHostsFile` to the name of the file you'd like to use:

```
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=$HOME/.ssh/known_hosts user@host...
```

However, you should test this. Ssh might complain about using a file that belongs to another user, and if it has to update the file then the file might end up being owned by root.

Really, you're best off running ssh as the user whose `.ssh` folder you want ssh to use. Running processes through `sudo` creates a risk that the user can find a way to do things you didn't intend for them to do. You should limit that risk by using the elevated privileges as little as possible.

Comment: I often ran into file permission problems after such tricks. Keep in mind that _if_ ssh complies the file will still get created by the user root. So subsequent ssh calls by the normal user will fail to write that file...

Comment: Thanks for the reply Kenster.  The problem is that this script has several things that it does that require root authority (hence the script being run via sudo).  I would have thought that by keeping certain env variables intact that the called binaries within the script would use that information instead of the elevated account information.   So far it looks like the steps I have taken are the only viable solution.